# combine 3query for s_p

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
select Month(user_lastlogin) as Month,year(user_lastlogin) as Year,
count(*) as 'Total             Reg' from bb_user 
group by Month(user_lastlogin),year(user_lastlogin)
order by  Month desc

select count(*) as 'LR Reg' from bb_user 
where  user_regtype ='LR'
group by Month(user_lastlogin)
order by  Month desc

select count(*) as 'BBR Reg' from bb_user 
where  user_regtype is null OR user_regtype = 'BBR'
group by Month(user_lastlogin)
order by  Month desc
```

I want to display like 
Month/Year/Total Reg/LR Reg/BBR Reg

I am displying result in 3 different query But I want In one Query I want to write stored procedure ....means I want to add 2nd and 3rd query in 1st query .

user_lastlogin = RegistrationDatetime

Comment: Do you really want the `LR Reg/BBR Reg` for current month from all years?

Comment: Also your syntax don't match sql server.

Comment: I want result like Month/Year/Total Reg/LR Reg/BBR Reg - 9(month)/2013/1000/300/700 ....8(month)/2013/2000/600/1400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT MONTH(user_lastlogin) AS Month,
       YEAR(user_lastlogin) AS Year,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Total Reg',
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_regtype = 'LR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'LR Reg',
       SUM(CASE WHEN IS NULL OR user_regtype = 'BBR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'BBR Reg'
  FROM bb_user 
GROUP BY MONTH(user_lastlogin), YEAR(user_lastlogin)
ORDER BY Year DESC, Month DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation is very unclear, but i think this is what you want in fact.

```
select
  Month(user_lastlogin) as Month,
  year(user_lastlogin) as Year,
  count(*) as [Total Reg],
  SUM(CASE WHEN user_regtype ='LR' THEN 1 END) [LR Reg],
  SUM(CASE WHEN user_regtype is null OR user_regtype = 'BBR THEN 1 END) [BBR Reg]
from bb_user 
group by
  Month(user_lastlogin),
  year(user_lastlogin)
order by  Month desc
```

Comment: Thanks ..working this      select
  Month(user_lastlogin) as Month,
  year(user_lastlogin) as Year,
  count(*) as 'Total Reg',
  SUM(CASE WHEN user_regtype ='LR' THEN 1 END) [LR Reg],
  SUM(CASE WHEN user_regtype is null OR user_regtype = 'BBR' THEN 1 END) [BBR Reg]
from bb_user 
group by
  Month(user_lastlogin),
  year(user_lastlogin)
order by  Month desc